# Django - Update operation on nester serialized object (Many to Many)

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-serializer

I want to update a nester serializer field, below example i want to update the field **teacher_date**

Here is my patch call with data

```
    {
        "user": {
            "pk": 2,
            "username": "rayees",
            "email": "rayees.xxxx@xxxx.co.in",
            "first_name": "Rayees",
            "last_name": "xxxxx",
            "user_type": "Teacher"
        },
        "first_name": "Rayees",
        "last_name": "xxxx",
        "bio": "TEST BIO",
        "teacher_cost": "22.00",
        "subject": [
            "HINDI",
            "ENGLISH"
        ],
        "teacher_date": [
            {
                "day_available": "MON",
                "time_available": "Morning"
            },
            {
                "day_available": "SUN",
                "time_available": "Morning"
            }
        ],
        "cities": [
            "SANTA CLARA",
            "SUNNYVALE"
        ]
    }
```

In this example everything get updated except **teacher_date**

**Model.py**

```
class Availability(models.Model):
    uid = models.AutoField(verbose_name='ID', 
                                  serialize=False, 
                                  auto_created=True, 
                                  primary_key=True)
    MONDAY = 'MON'
    TUESDAY = 'TUE'
    WEDNESDAY = "WED"
    THURSDAY = "THU"
    FRIDAY = 'FRI'
    SATURDAY = "SAT"
    SUNDAY = "SUN"
    DAY = (
        (MONDAY, 'Monday'),
        (TUESDAY, 'Tuesday'),
        (WEDNESDAY, 'Wednesday'),
        (THURSDAY, 'Thursday'),
        (FRIDAY, 'Friday'),
        (SATURDAY, 'Saturday'),
        (SUNDAY, 'Sunday'),
    )
    day_available = models.CharField(
        max_length=3, choices=DAY, default=MONDAY)

    MORNING = 'Morning'
    NOON = 'AfterNoon'
    EVENING = 'Evening'
    TIME = (
        (MORNING, 'Morning'),
        (NOON, 'Afternoon'),
        (EVENING, 'Evening'),
    )

    time_available = models.CharField(
        max_length=30, choices=TIME, default=MORNING)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.day_available} {self.time_available}"


class Teacher(models.Model):
    uid = models.AutoField(verbose_name='ID', 
                                  serialize=False, 
                                  auto_created=True, 
                                  primary_key=True)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    bio = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    teacher_cost = models.DecimalField(
        max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
    languages = models.CharField(
        max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)

    subject = models.ManyToManyField('Subject')
    teacher_date = models.ManyToManyField(Availability)
    cities = models.ManyToManyField('City', related_name='teacher')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

**serializer.py**

```
class AvailabilityDetails(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Availability
        fields = ('day_available', 'time_available',)

class TeacherProfileDetails(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    teacher_date = AvailabilityDetails(many=True, read_only=True)
    first_name = serializers.CharField(source='user.first_name', read_only=True)
    last_name = serializers.CharField(source='user.last_name', read_only=True)
    cities = serializers.SlugRelatedField(many=True, slug_field='city', queryset=City.objects.all(),)
    subject = serializers.SlugRelatedField(many=True, slug_field='subject', queryset=Subject.objects.all(),)
    teacher_date = AvailabilityDetails(many=True)
    user = UserDetailsSerializer(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Teacher
        fields = ('user', 'first_name', 'last_name', 
                  'bio', 'teacher_cost', 'subject', 'teacher_date', 'cities')

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        self.logger.info("-------- Inside the update --------------")
        teacher_date = validated_data.pop('teacher_date')
        self.logger.info(teacher_date)
        teacher_date = instance
        teacher_date.__dict__.update(validated_data)
        teacher_date.save()
        return teacher_date
```

Here I am doing some mistake in serialization, for teacher_date,  update method getting called during patch operation, but newly added values are not getting updated in DB

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop through validated data for teacher_date and save it first and then add to teacher instance. This is how many-to-many Field works
The instance in TeacherProfileDetails is Teacher not a Availibility intance

```py
def update(self, instance, validated_data):
    self.logger.info("-------- Inside the update --------------")
    # you other code
    teacher_date = validated_data.pop('teacher_date')
    if teacher_date:
        # first clear existing relations
        instance.teacher_date.clear()
        for date in teacher_date:
            availability = Availability.objects.create(**date)
            instance.teacher_date.add(availability)
    # you other code
    return teacher_date
```

Comment: I think this code will remove everything and keep only teacher_date,  I need to update some other field also, with this change I am getting the error 

`'list' object has no attribute 'subject'`